# How can I find if there is a submatrix in a numpy matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a 8x8 boolean matrix, and i would like to find if there is a submatrix in that matrix in the shape of 3x3 with only "False" in it.

for example:

the submatrix:

```
[[False, False, False],
[False, False, False],
[False, False, False]]
```

a matrix that have room for the submatrix (top left corner):

```
array([[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, True, False, True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, True, False, False, False, True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]])
```

a matrix that does not have room for the submatrix:

```
array([[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, True, False, True, False, True, False, False],
       [False, True, False, False, True, False, False, True],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, True, False, True, False, True, False, False],
       [False, False, True, False, False, False, True, False],
       [False, True, False, False, True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, True, False, False, True, False]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the sliding window approach with window of size 3x3:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view



x = np.array([[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
              [False, False, False, False, True, False, True, False],
              [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
              [False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False],
              [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
              [False, True, False, False, False, True, False, False],
              [False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False],
              [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]])


v = sliding_window_view(x, (3, 3))

v.sum(axis=(2,3))

array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1],
       [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1]])
```

where the locations of 0's are the locations of the upper-left corner of the submatrix in the matrix.

Edit: If you have any submatrix `s`, not with only False in it, you can do the following:

```
np.all(v == s, axis=(2,3))
```

and look for the locations of True values.

Comment: About the edit: What if i want an unsquared matrix?
Such as 
`s = np.array([[False],[False],[False]])`

Comment: @Noam then just use `s.shape` instead of `(3, 3)`. Like this: `v = sliding_window_view(x, s.shape)`